Change to quote of custom built product
We got a quote from signature quarters in Oklahoma this quote was approved and signed off
The trailer is half done and they have just sent me an updated quote much higher and also stated 5% will be added at end that was not in quote.  Is this allowed?

This site doesn't give legal advice.  It could be a legitimate cost overrun on a project, or an illegal bait-and-switch tactic, but there isn't enough information to make that determination.  A quote may or may not be a contract, you'd have to speak with an attorney to help you make that determination.
